# How to retain the changes in the QEMU VM image?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I want to use QEMU to emulate Linux OS and create a Virtual Machine (VM) for [Tiny Core Linux (TCL)](http://tinycorelinux.net/). I used the following commands the run TCL VM via QEMU.

First, I created a VM image in qcow2 format (I also tried to create `.img` image but it seems to have the same effect).:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 TCLcoredisk.qcow2 1G
```

Then, I booted the TCL by QEMU emulator. It works well, and I can do some operations in the VM (e.g., create a new directory and file, mount a file system).

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d \
    -cdrom Core-current.iso \
    -m 500 \
    -hda TCLcoredisk.qcow2 \
    -nographic \
    -enable-kvm \
    -curses
```

The issue was that after I shut down the QEMU (pkill the QEMU process), I cannot retain the changes I made by booting the previous image file. Worse, I cannot even boot the image. I can only boot by `-cdrom` with the `.iso` image file but changes will be lost. However, as I mounted a file system on a newly-created directory during the first boot, all the information of first booting was lost if I boot the `TCLcoredisk.qcow2` image file again. I used the following command to boot this existing image file:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive "file=TCLcoredisk.qcow2,format=qcow2" \
    -m 500 \
    -nographic \ 
    -enable-kvm \
    -curses
```

I got the error `Nothing to boot: No such file or directory (http://ipxe.org/2d03e13b)`. My host machine only supports command line without using graphical interfaces, that is why I used `-nographic` and `-curses`. I also want to use TCL only by command line. I guess I don't need to use the `.iso` image file anymore after the first boot. Is there a way that I can boot the existing image file properly and retain the changes in the previous booting? Thank you!

Comment: The next boot should be `-boot c` booting from the harddisk instead of `boot -d`. Can you try it ??

Comment: @nhatnq Thanks. I tried using `-boot c` but it still had the same error `Nothing to boot: No such file or directory (http://ipxe.org/2d03e13b)` and `No bootable device.` I wonder if there is a way to check whether the OS and my changes had been written into the image file. I am not sure if the issue was from the image file or the wrong command. Should the next boot command include network configurations and/or other configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pointed that on FAQ Tiny Core Linux only bases on RAM. Thus you cannot use a persistent filesystem

> What is the boot architecture?
>
> Tinycore always boots to ram. This unique way has several advantages,
> like 100% functioning usb boot, awesome speed, and being able to boot
> without having the ability to access the boot device after booting.
> You're free to snag out the usb drive right after initrd is loaded,
> for example.
> https://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/faq.html#arch

You will need to use another distribution

Comment: Thanks. Great point. Is there a way for QEMU to handle this case (i.e., persist RAM-based OS)?

Comment: @Jeffrey I think no unless you can try another distribution which supports disk spaces e.g Ubuntu, Fedora. Alpine is also a choice for lightweight